# Multiple sites that share some pages, but not others

Tags: multisite

I'm pretty new to WordPress...
I'm trying to set up a few sites, each with their own top level domain name. What I want them to do is share some of the pages, but not others. For example - they would all share Services, Contact, and Team pages; but would each have their own Biography page.

When one of the shared pages is updated, they're all updated.

I can't figure out if WP multisite is this or not? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible. The only way is to create the page in each site or add a custom link to one main page but doing this will show only that sites theme

Comment: This is all possible using a custom built plugin.

Comment: do you think you can give us a test of what it would take then. last time I asked someone like this they said it was .not possible to make a plungin like this.

Comment: I am working on a proof of concept at the moment. I'll post it here soon.

Comment: Sounds Good Azizur